# How to extract property of pandas index from string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, datetimeindex

I have a question, How can I extract index property from string variable in pandas?
I want to extract particular properties from datetime index in a loop.
code attached below:

```
features_list = ['dayofweek',
             'dayofyear',
             'day',
             'year',
             'month',
             'daysinmonth',
             'is_leap_year',
             'is_month_end',
             'is_quarter_end',
             'is_year_end',
             'is_month_start',
             'is_quarter_start',
             'is_year_start',
             'quarter',
             'week']
for feat from features_list:
    dataset[f'{feat}'] = dataset.index.feat
```

so if the value in feat variable is day, the string must be 'dataset.index.day'.
if it is week, the string must be 'dataset.index.week'?

Comment: use `eval` to get from string to property. 
`dataset[f'{feat}'] = eval("dataset.index."+feat )`

Comment: thank you very much! Works like a charm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eval to get from string to property.

```
dataset[f'{feat}'] = eval("dataset.index."+feat )
```